# Failed to deploy war file on one node in weblogic 12c

Tags: java

I tried to deploy a war file on two Nodes in weblogic 12c. Deployment was sucessfull on node 1 and It is failng on node 2. I am geting following error in console "javax.servlet.ServletException" and error in log "

**Errors I am getting in logs while trying to deploy:**

```
<Error> <Deployer> <Server name.clientname.com> <wlsManaged1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1488320025949> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1488320025506" for task "64". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: javax.servlet.ServletException"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: javax.servlet.ServletException
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleLis

<Warning> <J2EE> <server.client.com> <wlsManaged1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1488319967148> <BEA-160140> <Unresolved optional package references (in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF): [Extension-Name: Lib-LifelineSSO, Specification-Version: 1, referenced from: /Drive/oracle/admin/wlsDomain1/servers/wlsManaged1/tmp/_WL_user/CpcWeb/jli9xy/war]. Ensure that the referenced optional package has been deployed as a library.>


<Error> <HTTP> <server.clientname..com> <wlsManaged1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1488320025874> <BEA-101165> <Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: com.clientname.cpc.web.JmxRegistrationFilter.
javax.servlet.ServletException
        at com.clientname.cpc.web.JmxRegistrationFilter.init(JmxRegistrationFilter.java:72)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:577)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.loadFilter(FilterManager.java:137)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.preloadFilters(FilterManager.java:
```

Comment: Please update your original post with the full stack trace.

Comment: Check the weblogic log to see if you have any problems with the size of the tablespace